# case insensitive search with index on property of a node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to do case insensitive seach for a property of a node which should use index on that property. I am using Neo4j 2.2.3. With regular expression, we can search but it will not use index on that property, e.g -

```
MATCH (e:Entity)-[r]->(a:Address)  where a.state=~'.*(?i)nm.*' RETURN r
```

If i am wrong, plese correct me and let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=~` operator does not use indexes. In 2.3 exact matches (`=`), ranges (`>`, `<`) use indexes as well as `STARTS WITH`. All other conditions are not index backed.

If you use [`manual indexes`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html) you can use the full power of Lucene query syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan for clarification

Comment: I am using 2.2.3. Is START WITH and exact match backed with index in 2.2.3?

Comment: Exact match:yes, STARTS WITH has been added in 2.3

Comment: Is ENDS WITH also backed with index in Neo4j 2.3?